# Put image for background in wxpython panel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to put an image for background to a panel in wxpython and that image  when i resize my panel i want of course to resize the image .Can any one help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND` event and bind it.
[Code example](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/)

Pay attention and read distinctly. The first listing represents bad practice.